# Spray route not working as expected. GET request also executes DELETE

Tags: json, scala, routes, spray

Some routing is automatically executed. I think it has something to do with code in Api.scala

- POST and PUT work fine. Weather I execute GET or DELETE, both get executed. Just wondering why?
- During startup GET /api/v1/adsresgistrations gets executed
- Is there a better way of organizing the routes?

**RegistrationsRoute.scala**

```
package com.admcore.api

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import spray.util.LoggingContext
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import spray.routing._
import spray.json._
import spray.http.StatusCodes
import spray.httpx.marshalling._
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._
import akka.actor.ActorRef
import akka.pattern.ask
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Success
import scala.util.Failure
import scala.language.postfixOps
import com.admcore.service.RegistrationsService.{GetRegistrationsMessage, GetRegistrationMessage, PostRegistrationMessage, PutRegistrationMessage, DeleteRegistrationMessage} 
import com.admcore.model.{Registration, RegistrationJsonProtocol}
import com.admcore.model.RegistrationJsonProtocol._
import com.admcore.Services

class RegistrationsRoutes(services: Services)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext, log: LoggingContext) extends ApiRoute(services) {

  import com.admcore.api.ApiRoute._
  import ApiRouteProtocol._
  import com.admcore.model.RegistrationJsonProtocol._

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)

  val route: Route = {
    pathPrefix("adsregistrations") {
      pathEnd {
        post {
          entity(as[Registration]) { registration =>
            withService("adsRegistrations") { service =>
              val future = (service ? PostRegistrationMessage(registration)).mapTo[Registration]

              onComplete(future) {
                case Success(result) =>
                  complete(result.toString)

                case Failure(e) =>
                  log.error(s"Error: ${e.toString}")
                  complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, Message(ApiMessages.UnknownException))
              }
            }
          }
        } ~
        put {
          entity(as[Registration]) { registration =>
            withService("adsRegistrations") { service =>
              val future = (service ? PutRegistrationMessage(registration)).mapTo[Registration]

              onComplete(future) {
                case Success(result) =>
                  complete(result.toString)

                case Failure(e) =>
                  log.error(s"Error: ${e.toString}")
                  complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, Message(ApiMessages.UnknownException))
              }
            }
          }
        } ~
        get {
          withService("adsRegistrations") { service =>
            val future = (service ? GetRegistrationsMessage()).mapTo[Vector[Registration]]

            onComplete(future) {
              case Success(result) =>
                complete(Message(result.toString))

              case Failure(e) =>
                log.error(s"Error: ${e.toString}")
                complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, Message(ApiMessages.UnknownException))
            }
          }
        }
      } ~
      pathPrefix(Segment) { (registrationId) =>
        pathEnd {
          delete {
            withService("adsRegistrations") { service =>
              val future = (service ? DeleteRegistrationMessage(registrationId)).mapTo[Registration]

              onComplete(future) {
                case Success(result) =>
                  complete(Message(result.toString))

                case Failure(e) =>
                  log.error(s"Error: ${e.toString}")
                  complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, Message(ApiMessages.UnknownException))
              }
            }
          } ~
          get {
            withService("adsRegistrations") { service =>
              val future = (service ? GetRegistrationMessage(registrationId)).mapTo[Registration]

              onComplete(future) {
                case Success(result) =>
                  complete(Message(result.toString))

                case Failure(e) =>
                  log.error(s"Error: ${e.toString}")
                  complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, Message(ApiMessages.UnknownException))
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Registration.scala**

```
package model

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging}
import spray.json._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import org.bson.types.ObjectId
import com.mongodb.DBObject
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.{MongoDBList, MongoDBObject}

case class Registration(
  system: String, 
  identity: String, 
  id: Option[String] = None)

object RegistrationJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val adsRegistrationFormat = jsonFormat3(Registration)
}
```

**RegistrationsService.scala**

```
package com.admcore.service

import akka.actor.{Props, ActorLogging, Actor}
import spray.json._
import com.mongodb.util.JSON
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import com.admcore.DBConfiguration
import com.admcore.MongoContext
import com.admcore.model.{Registration, RegistrationDAO}


object RegistrationsService {
  case class PostRegistrationMessage(registration: Registration)
  case class PutRegistrationMessage(registration: Registration)
  case class DeleteRegistrationMessage(registrationId: String)
  case class GetRegistrationMessage(registrationId: String)
  case class GetRegistrationsMessage()

  def props(property: String) = Props(classOf[RegistrationsService], property)
}

class RegistrationsService(property: String) extends Actor with ActorLogging with DBConfiguration {
  import RegistrationsService._

  def receive = {    
    case PostRegistrationMessage(registration) => {
      log.debug(s"POST ${registration}")

      val dao = new RegistrationDAO(mongoContext.adsRegistrations)
      val result = dao.insert(registration)
      log.debug(s"result: $result")

      sender() ! result.get
    }

    case PutRegistrationMessage(registration) => {
      log.debug(s"PUT ${registration}")

      val dao = new RegistrationDAO(mongoContext.adsRegistrations)
      val result = dao.update(registration)
      log.debug(s"result: $result")

      sender() ! result.get
    }

    case DeleteRegistrationMessage(registrationId) => {
      log.debug(s"DELETE ${registrationId}")

      val dao = new RegistrationDAO(mongoContext.adsRegistrations)
      val result = dao.delete(registrationId)
      log.debug(s"result: $result")

      sender() ! result.get
    }

    case GetRegistrationMessage(registrationId) => {
      log.debug(s"GET ${registrationId}")

      val dao = new RegistrationDAO(mongoContext.adsRegistrations)
      val result = dao.findOne(new ObjectId(registrationId))
      log.debug(s"result: $result")

      sender() ! result.get
    }

    case GetRegistrationsMessage() => {
      log.debug(s"GET all ADS registration")

      val dao = new RegistrationDAO(mongoContext.adsRegistrations)
      val result = dao.find()
      log.debug(s"result: $result")

      sender() ! result
    }
  }
}
```

**Api.scala**

```
package com.admcore.api

import spray.routing._
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorLogging, Props}
import akka.io.IO
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import spray.can.Http
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import spray.util.LoggingContext
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport
import spray.http.HttpHeaders.{`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`}
import spray.http.HttpMethods._
import spray.http.{StatusCodes, HttpOrigin, SomeOrigins}
import com.admcore.util.ConfigHolder
import com.admcore.{Services, Core, CoreActors}

trait CORSSupport extends Directives {
  private val CORSHeaders = List(
    `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`(GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS),
    `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`("Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Host, Referer, User-Agent"),
    `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`(true)
  )

  def respondWithCORS(origin: String)(routes: => Route) = {
    val originHeader = `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`(SomeOrigins(Seq(HttpOrigin(origin))))

    respondWithHeaders(originHeader :: CORSHeaders) {
      routes ~ options { complete(StatusCodes.OK) }
    }
  }
}

trait Api extends Directives with RouteConcatenation with CORSSupport with ConfigHolder {
  this: CoreActors with Core =>

  val routes =
    respondWithCORS(config.getString("origin.domain")) {
      pathPrefix("api" / "v1") {
        new RegistrationsRoutes(services).route
      }
    }

  val rootService = system.actorOf(ApiService.props(config.getString("hostname"), config.getInt("port"), routes))
}

object ApiService {
  def props(hostname: String, port: Int, routes: Route) = Props(classOf[ApiService], hostname, port, routes)
}

class ApiService(hostname: String, port: Int, routes: Route) extends HttpServiceActor with ActorLogging {
  IO(Http)(context.system) ! Http.Bind(self, hostname, port)

  def receive: Receive = runRoute(routes)
}

object ApiRoute {
  case class Message(message: String)

  object ApiRouteProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val messageFormat = jsonFormat1(Message)
  }

  object ApiMessages {
    val UnknownException = "Unknown exception"
    val UnsupportedService = "Sorry, provided service is not supported."
  }
}

abstract class ApiRoute(services: Services = Services.empty)(implicit log: LoggingContext) extends Directives with SprayJsonSupport {

  import com.admcore.api.ApiRoute.{ApiMessages, Message}
  import com.admcore.api.ApiRoute.ApiRouteProtocol._

  def withService(id: String)(action: ActorRef => Route) = {
    services.get(id) match {
      case Some(provider) =>
        action(provider)

      case None =>
        log.error("Unsupported service: $id")
        complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest, Message(ApiMessages.UnsupportedService))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For the marshalling issue, are you importing `spray.httpx.marshalling._` ?

Comment: for # 1, check your code inside `GetRegistrationMessage`. Make sure you are not deleting inside this? # 2 Your routes look good to me.

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta - It is not in GetRegistrationMessage. I updated the question with that code as well now. I suspect it has to do something with the Api trait. I updated the question as well. Please take a look.

Comment: @tobym - It is imported, still getting error. Removed this part from question for now, just to focus on routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes are executed when they are being built and not at request-handling time: this applies to the GET request executed once as well as to the GET/DELETE executed simultaneously for every request. See the [spray docs](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/advanced-topics/understanding-dsl-structure/) for an detailed explanation. To fix this behaviour, pass your future to be evaluated directly to the `onComplete` directive instead of assigning it to a val. This will defer evaluation of the future until the respective request is actually handled. So instead of

```
get {
  withService("adsRegistrations") { service =>
    val future = (service ? GetRegistrationsMessage()).mapTo[Vector[Registration]]

    onComplete(future) {
      case Success(result) =>
        complete(Message(result.toString))

      case Failure(e) =>
        log.error(s"Error: ${e.toString}")
        complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, Message(ApiMessages.UnknownException))
    }
  }
}
```

use

```
get {
  withService("adsRegistrations") { service =>    
    onComplete((service ? GetRegistrationsMessage()).mapTo[Vector[Registration]]) {
      case Success(result) =>
        complete(Message(result.toString))

      case Failure(e) =>
        log.error(s"Error: ${e.toString}")
        complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, Message(ApiMessages.UnknownException))
    }
  }
```

**EDIT**: updated answer with possible fix

Comment: After some more reading, still couldn't figure out how to do this right. Created another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894780/get-is-failing-with-compilation-error to target just the auto execution during deployment. I think if I can get this right, I will know how to fix the other. Appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a possible fix that applies to should fix your issues.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Not assigning to val made all the difference.

Comment: Glad to hear. Declaring the futures as `lazy` would have also worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with for others benefit. I still need to figure out how to return a proper json string of the object instead of just toString, but that's for later. This code makes sure multiple methods are not executed per request and no method is run when the application is coming up.

```
package com.admcore.api

import akka.actor.ActorRef
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import spray.json._
import spray.routing._
import spray.http.StatusCodes
import spray.httpx.marshalling._
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._
import spray.util.LoggingContext
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

import com.admcore.Services
import com.admcore.model.Registration
import com.admcore.model.RegistrationJsonProtocol._
import com.admcore.service.RegistrationsService.{
    GetRegistrationsMessage, GetRegistrationMessage, 
    PostRegistrationMessage, PutRegistrationMessage, DeleteRegistrationMessage 
} 

class RegistrationsRoutes(services: Services)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext, log: LoggingContext) extends ApiRoute(services) {

  import com.admcore.api.ApiRoute._
  import ApiRouteProtocol._

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)

  val getAllRegistrations = pathPrefix("adsregistrations") & pathEnd & get
  val postRegistration = pathPrefix("adsregistrations") & pathEnd & post
  val putRegistration = pathPrefix("adsregistrations" / Segment) & pathEnd & put
  val deleteRegistration = pathPrefix("adsregistrations" / Segment) & pathEnd & delete
  val getRegistration = pathPrefix("adsregistrations" / Segment) & pathEnd & get

  val route: Route = {
    withService("registrations") { service =>
      getAllRegistrations {
        onComplete((service ? GetRegistrationsMessage()).mapTo[Vector[Registration]]) {
          case Success(result) =>
            complete(Message(result.toString))

          case Failure(e) =>
            log.error(s"Error: ${e.toString}")
            complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, Message(ApiMessages.UnknownException))
        }
      } ~
      postRegistration {
        entity(as[Registration]) { registration =>
          val future = (service ? PostRegistrationMessage(registration)).mapTo[Registration]

          onComplete(future) {
            case Success(result) =>
              complete(result.toString)

            case Failure(e) =>
              log.error(s"Error: ${e.toString}")
              complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, Message(ApiMessages.UnknownException))
          }          
        }
      } ~
      putRegistration { registrationId =>
        entity(as[Registration]) { registration =>
          val future = (service ? PutRegistrationMessage(registration)).mapTo[Registration]

          onComplete(future) {
            case Success(result) =>
              complete(result.toString)

            case Failure(e) =>
              log.error(s"Error: ${e.toString}")
              complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, Message(ApiMessages.UnknownException))
          }
        }
      } ~
      deleteRegistration { registrationId =>
        val future = (service ? DeleteRegistrationMessage(registrationId)).mapTo[Registration]

        onComplete(future) {
          case Success(result) =>
            complete(Message(result.toString))

          case Failure(e) =>
            log.error(s"Error: ${e.toString}")
            complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, Message(ApiMessages.UnknownException))
        }
      } ~
      getRegistration { registrationId =>
        val future = (service ? GetRegistrationMessage(registrationId)).mapTo[Registration]

        onComplete(future) {
          case Success(result) =>
            complete(Message(result.toString))

          case Failure(e) =>
            log.error(s"Error: ${e.toString}")
            complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, Message(ApiMessages.UnknownException))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```